# checkbox pass element this

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a bit of a problem, i have just inherited a colleague script and while i maintain his code, i am rewriting his, so that being said my problem is with the check boxes i can change the checks but after that i want to send the box that has been changed the element
so here is the on when i do the change

```
$(":checkbox[value=" + valu + "]").prop("checked","true");
```

and then i want to send it to his function: `add2this(this, type);`

```
var arrTmp // global array

function test( valu ){

    $(":checkbox[value=" + valu + "]").prop("checked","true");
    add2this(this, 'List');
}

function add2this(ths, type){

         switch (type) {
               case "List":
                if (ths.checked) {
                          arrTmp.push(vl);
                 }
                 break;
                 default:
                      break;
          }
}
```

hopefully the code will help to understand better

thanks

Comment: Please provide some jsfiddle or another example to better understand your case.

Comment: `add2this($(":checkbox[value=" + valu + "]"), type);`

Comment: hi thanks for that but unfortunately there is code "if (ths.checked) " does not recognize, if i pass what u recommened

Answer (score 1):

Your function is not passing the checkbox itself. You are using keyword "this" in a place where it does not mean what you think it means. You need to use jquery .each() .

```
function test( valu ){

    $(":checkbox[value=" + valu + "]")
         .prop("checked","true")
         .each(function(){ add2this(this, 'List'); });

}
```